# Spring Boot - Order of Bean creation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there any default bean initialization order implicitly in a Spring Boot application? I came across this question in one of my Spring Boot applications when trying to use @ConditionalOnBean annotation.

At first, I thought that Spring does not guarantee any Bean creation order when it's loading beans in @Configuration class or when it's doing component-scan to auto register @Component/@Service/.. classes.

But later, I noticed that in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-bean-conditions), it mentions that,

> Auto-configuration classes are guaranteed to load after any user-defined bean definitions have been added.

This somehow makes me confused,
1. What counts *user defined bean* and what counts *auto-configuration classes*? Specifically, is there any loading order between @Bean in @Configuration class and @Component/@Service directly on class level.
2. If a bean A needs dependency injection of bean B, will B always be initialized first?
3. If @Import is used for configuration aggregation in a Spring Boot application, will beans defined in the imported configuration class being initialized before component-scanned bean registration.

```java
@Component
public class A {}

@Component
public class B {
    @Autowired
    private A a;
}

@Configuration
public class externalConfig {
    @Bean
    public C c() {
        return new C();
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(externalConfig.class)
public class testApplication {
    @Bean
    public D d() {
        return new D();
    }
}
```

When comes to the above code example, my question becomes the following.
1. Without @Import, will C or D always be initialized before A and B?
2. Will B always be initialized before A?
3. With @Import, will C always be initialized first, like even before D?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but:

1. No there is no guarantee.
2. A will be initialized, then B, cause you're injecting A.
3. Import is not guaranteeing the order, only if you have some not lazy injections

Check the DependsOn annotation ([enter link description here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-depends-on)).

I hope it helps you,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your answer seems to contradict to what I quoted above from the Spring documentations. If there is no guarantee, what guarantee it refer to in terms of **Auto-configuration classes are guaranteed to load after any user-defined bean definitions have been added.**